# Напишите функцию которая генерирует матрицу размером m*n случайными целыми числами в диапазоне [-50,50]

Tags: python, list, матрицы, случайные-числа

```
from random import randint
def create_random_array(m,n):
  m = int(input())
  n = int(input())
  a = []
  for i in range (m+1):
      for j in range(n+1):
           a =randint(-50,50)
return(a)
```

Comment: Напишите. Вопрос надо формулировать, сейчас вопроса нет, есть только код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
from random import randint

def create_random_array(m,n):
    a = []
    for i in range (m):
        new_row = []
        for j in range(n):
            new_row.append(randint(-50,50))
        a.append(new_row)
    return(a)
```

Ошибки:

1. Либо передавайте размер матрицы при вызове функции, либо `input`ами. Выберите что то одно
2. Чтобы добавлять элемент в список есть метод `append`

В действительности функцию можно сократить до пары строк, но думаю, что вам будет сложно понять. Обратитесь к такой штуке как [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Вызов

```py
create_random_array(5,10)
```

Результат

```py
[[24, 13, -17, 41, 21, 29, 33, 23, -2, 3], 
[48, 15, 9, 1, 30, 12, -11, 31, 23, -10], 
[-5, -3, -20, -17, -2, 7, -44, 14, 29, -46], 
[13, -9, -2, -25, 20, 33, 32, -6, -47, 27], 
[-34, 19, -8, -17, 50, 39, -23, -26, -24, -28]]
```

**UPD**

Код покороче и для новичков не всегда ясен

```py
def create_random_array(m,n):
    return [[randint(-50,50) for row in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
```

но выполняет ту же функцию

Comment: Благодарю очень помогло

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то вот так. Через лямбда функцию.

```
import random

create_random_array = lambda n, m: [[random.randint(-50, 50) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

n, m = map(int, input().split())

print(create_random_array(n, m))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое